# Managing Concurrent PDF Uploads: How to Dynamically Link Questions to Specific PDF Files for Seamless Communication with ChatGPT?

Tags: express, pdf, nlp, openai-api, chat-gpt-4

In my current project, I'm dealing with a scenario where multiple PDF files are being uploaded simultaneously. While implementing this functionality, I've encountered a challenge related to efficiently managing communication between the user and specific PDF files. Specifically, I'm looking for a solution that allows me to send questions directly to ChatGPT and receive responses in a way that corresponds to the relevant PDF file. I want to establish a seamless connection between user queries and the respective PDFs to streamline the communication process. Any insights or guidance on how to achieve this dynamic linking between questions and specific PDF files would be greatly appreciated.

As of now, I've explored various approaches to tackle the issue of dynamically linking questions to specific PDF files during concurrent uploads. Initially, I attempted to assign unique identifiers or tags to each uploaded PDF, hoping to use these as reference points for communication with ChatGPT. However, I've encountered challenges in implementing a robust and scalable solution.

I expected that by leveraging these identifiers, I could establish a clear correspondence between user questions and the relevant PDFs, enabling a seamless interaction process with ChatGPT. Unfortunately, the current implementation falls short, and I'm seeking insights or alternative strategies that developers with more experience in this area may have employed successfully. Any suggestions or examples of effective solutions would be immensely valuable in overcoming this hurdle.